# While loop keeps going back to end condition

Tags: python, loops

I'm just going over some python basics, and wrote some code that I thought would print every even element inside of a list:

```
def print_evens(numbers):
    """Prints all even numbers in the list
    """
    length = len(numbers)
    i = 0
    while i < length:
        if numbers[i] % 2 == 0:
            print (numbers[i])
            i += 1
            
print_evens([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

I'm not sure why but the loop doesn't go past the end condition and just keeps cycling back and forth. I feel I'm missing something very simple.

If I had to guess where the problem lies, I'd say it's with the if statement, though I'm not sure what would be wrong about it.

Comment: assuming the indentation in your question is as it is in your code, you only change the value of i if the if returns true, otherwise it just makes the same check again, and then again, and then again.

Comment: Unindent the `i+=1` outside of the if statement.

Comment: @TZHX That makes sense, though I just tried to fix the indentation and it still doesn't work. To clarify, it doesn't even go past the if statement, just keeps checking if i < length. Update: You were correct, I just didn't fix the indentation properly. Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you start with `1` the variable `i` never get updated, because it's not even. So the solution is to increment the `i` every time without a condition:

```
while i < length:
        if numbers[i] % 2 == 0:
            print (numbers[i])
        i += 1
```

Comment: Ah ok I see now, this worked thank you. Turns out I was just goldilocks-ing the indentation for `i += 1`. I was either putting it too far left or too far right haha

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to bother with indexes you can loop directly on the list items.

```py
def print_evens(numbers):
    """Prints all even numbers in the list
    """
    for n in numbers:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            print(n)
```